# Feathersjs API ES6 class hooks and rest undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, feathersjs

I am setting up a feathers-client using a ES6 class which I want to import in the actions of my React-Redux-Webpack application.

I have setup a REST api using the awesome Feathers scaffold.

Unfortunately I get an error in the browser which is ruining my day. What am I doing wrong?

> Uncaught TypeError: _client2.default.hooks is not a function

Can anyone help me out? Why are `hooks` (and also `rest`) undefined here? Packages seem to be installed properly...

Is the following a good idea?

```
// src/middleware/api.js

import hooks from 'feathers-hooks'
import feathers from 'feathers/client'
import rest from 'feathers-rest/client'

class API {
  constructor() {
    const connection = process.env.FEATHERS_API_URL
    this.app = feathers()
      .configure(feathers.hooks())
      .configure(rest(connection).fetch(fetch))
      .configure(feathers.authentication({
        type: 'local',
        storage: window.localStorage,
      }))
  }
}
```

Could it be that some packages aren't compatible?

```
"feathers": "^2.0.3",
    "feathers-authentication": "^0.7.12",
    "feathers-client": "^1.8.0",
    "feathers-configuration": "^0.3.3",
    "feathers-errors": "^2.5.0",
    "feathers-hooks": "^1.7.1",
    "feathers-rest": "^1.5.2",
    "feathers-sequelize": "^1.4.0"
```

Another thing I'm wondering about is do we always need to feed the `rest` function a path? Can it default to use the path used in the config files? Feeding it a path feels a bit weird having both my client and server side code in the same project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@feathersjs/client` is a bundle that includes a set of Feathers standard modules (like auth, rest, socketio clients) and can be used directly in the browser (see [the documentation here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client.html)).

It looks like you are trying to use a module loader [which is documented here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client.html#module-loaders) so instead of using the pre-bundled package (where everything is in the `feathers.` namespace like `feathers.hooks`, `feathers.authentication` etc.) you can import only the modules that you need and configure them:

```
  // src/middleware/api.js
  import feathers from '@feathersjs/feathers'
  import rest from '@feathersjs/rest-client'
  import authentication from '@feathersjs/authentication-client'

  class API {
    constructor() {
      const connection = process.env.FEATHERS_API_URL
      this.app = feathers()
        .configure(rest(connection).fetch(fetch))
        .configure(authentication({
          type: 'local',
          storage: window.localStorage,
        }))
    }
  }
```

`rest` does not require a base url if it is running on the same domain. It is an empty string by default.

Comment: That clears up a lot! Very helpful. Thanks!

Another thing, right now I'm using feathers-authentication v0.7.12. I would love to use the newest versions but have some code running already. Should I be able to safely do major updates for all the feathers packages? Or is there some documentation on how to do this?

Comment: You can find the authentication 1.0 migration guide in https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/blob/master/docs/migrating.md.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I read "Response to app.authenticate() does not return user".

Before I was able to set a currentUser in the state of my Redux store including an id based on the response. Now I am boggled; how can I smoothly get the right id back?

Comment: Should I setup after-hooks for ```authenticationService = app.service('/authentication')```? That doesn't seem to be the right way...

Comment: That was the idea. The problem with the old way was that it didn't run things like the `remove` hook (so if you didn't remove it manually before there was a chance of sending the encrypted password). Now you can just `return app.service('users').get(payload.userId).then(user => { hook.result.user = user; return hook; })` in an after hook to get the same thing.

Comment: I also read that "By default the payload for your JWT is simply your entity id". But when I log the payload in the after hook of all authentication service methods, I read undefined. Where exactly should the id be set in the payload? What do you think I'm missing?